# Comparing minitab output to R

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, minitab

I am trying to recreate analysis of diamond data in R and compare it to minitab output cited in http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v9n2/datasets.chu.html

I'm almost certain its the same data set yet my results are different. I suspect I'm modeling it differently. I also noticed that I'm missing colourD and some others. Did the the minitab model somehow pick different dummys to exclude?

**R OUTPUT**

```
require("Ecdat")

data(Diamond)

Diamond$ln_price <- log(Diamond$price)

summary(lm(ln_price~carat+colour+clarity+certification, data=Diamond))


Call:
lm(formula = ln_price ~ carat + colour + clarity + certification, 
    data = Diamond)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.31236 -0.11520  0.01613  0.10833  0.36339 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       6.8011915  0.0496111 137.090  < 2e-16 ***
carat             2.8550130  0.0369676  77.230  < 2e-16 ***
colourE          -0.0295093  0.0404611  -0.729  0.46638    
colourF          -0.1063582  0.0379807  -2.800  0.00544 ** 
colourG          -0.2063494  0.0389848  -5.293 2.35e-07 ***
colourH          -0.2878756  0.0394752  -7.293 2.81e-12 ***
colourI          -0.4165565  0.0413818 -10.066  < 2e-16 ***
clarityVS1       -0.2019313  0.0310634  -6.501 3.41e-10 ***
clarityVS2       -0.2985406  0.0333027  -8.964  < 2e-16 ***
clarityVVS1      -0.0007058  0.0311121  -0.023  0.98192    
clarityVVS2      -0.0966174  0.0289396  -3.339  0.00095 ***
certificationHRD -0.0088557  0.0208641  -0.424  0.67155    
certificationIGI -0.1827107  0.0249516  -7.323 2.33e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.1382 on 295 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9723,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.9712 
F-statistic: 863.6 on 12 and 295 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

**MINITAB OUTPUT**

```
ln_price = 6.08 + 2.86 Carat + 0.417 D + 0.387 E + 0.310 F + 0.210 G + 0.129 H
          + 0.299 IF + 0.298 VVS1 + 0.202 VVS2 + 0.0966 VS1 + 0.0089 GIA
           - 0.174 IGI

Predictor        Coef       StDev          T        P       
Constant      6.07724     0.04809     126.37    0.000
Carat         2.85501     0.03697      77.23    0.000      
D             0.41656     0.04138      10.07    0.000       
E             0.38705     0.03082      12.56    0.000       
F             0.31020     0.02748      11.29    0.000       
G             0.21021     0.02836       7.41    0.000       
H             0.12868     0.02852       4.51    0.000       
IF            0.29854     0.03330       8.96    0.000       
VVS1          0.29783     0.02810      10.60    0.000       
VVS2          0.20192     0.02534       7.97    0.000       
VS1           0.09661     0.02492       3.88    0.000       
GIA           0.00886     0.02086       0.42    0.672       
IGI          -0.17385     0.02867      -6.06    0.000       

S = 0.1382      R-Sq = 97.2%     R-Sq(adj) = 97.1%

Analysis of Variance

Source            DF          SS          MS         F        P
Regression        12     197.939      16.495    863.64    0.000
Residual Error   295       5.634       0.019
Total            307     203.574
```

**UPDATE**
Glen_b's solution produces the correct results, but the output is not desirable.

```
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           6.3846350  0.0411520 155.148  < 2e-16 ***
carat                 2.8550130  0.0369676  77.230  < 2e-16 ***
C(colour, base = 6)1  0.4165565  0.0413818  10.066  < 2e-16 ***
C(colour, base = 6)2  0.3870472  0.0308241  12.557  < 2e-16 ***
C(colour, base = 6)3  0.3101983  0.0274791  11.288  < 2e-16 ***
C(colour, base = 6)4  0.2102072  0.0283593   7.412 1.32e-12 ***
C(colour, base = 6)5  0.1286809  0.0285231   4.511 9.31e-06 ***
```

Is there a way to get the original factor character displayed instead of the level?

**UPDATE**

Using relevel to set the base to the same bases as the minitab produces the same results and is still readable.

```
  Diamond$colour <- relevel(Diamond$colour, ref="I")

  Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
  (Intercept)       6.3846350  0.0411520 155.148  < 2e-16 ***
  carat             2.8550130  0.0369676  77.230  < 2e-16 ***
  colourD           0.4165565  0.0413818  10.066  < 2e-16 ***
  colourE           0.3870472  0.0308241  12.557  < 2e-16 ***
  colourF           0.3101983  0.0274791  11.288  < 2e-16 ***
  colourG           0.2102072  0.0283593   7.412 1.32e-12 ***
  colourH           0.1286809  0.0285231   4.511 9.31e-06 ***
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The model (the specific parameters and X-matrix) is not exactly the same, clearly. Note that the baseline color (the reference group) in R is "D" while in Minitab it's "I" (see there's no coefficient for D in the R output and none for I in the Minitab output?).

Looking through, it looks like there are similar differences in the other categorical variables.

> Did the the minitab model somehow pick different dummys to exclude?

Yes.

You can make either one work the same as the other.

For example, see the checked answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002766/changing-reference-group-for-categorical-predictor-variable-in-logistic-regressi) for how to change the reference category of a factor in R.

(The question asks about logistic regression but the solution works quite generally.)

Comment: This lead me to relevel which is what I ended up going with

Comment: +1. Note that the same is true for clarity (inclusions in the stone), ie, `IF` is missing from R's output, & `VS2` is missing from minitab's output. It appears that minitab uses the *last* category as the reference level, whereas R uses the 1st by default. Because the ref level gets included in the intercept, that value differs, and how the other categories differ from the intercept differ as well.